# MySQL: Optimized join across tables

Tags: mysql, optimization, join, query-optimization

That query is slow (about 1.5 seconds).  It should simply return a list of posts

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE p.id 
    FROM 1_posts p 
    LEFT JOIN 1_topics t ON (p.cid = t.cid AND p.container = t.id) 
    WHERE t.cid = 1010699;
```

EXPLAIN gives:

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+-----------------------+-----------+---------+---------------+------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys         | key       | key_len | ref           | rows | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-------+------+-----------------------+-----------+---------+---------------+------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t     | ref  | PRIMARY,cid           | cid       | 4       | const         |  216 | Using where; Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | p     | ref  | PRIMARY,cid,container | container | 4       | forumdb.t.id |   49 | Using where              |
+----+-------------+-------+------+-----------------------+-----------+---------+---------------+------+--------------------------+
```

Note that SQL_NO_CACHE is there for testing purposes only.

Partial structure of tables:

1_posts:

```
mysql> explain 1_posts;
+----------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type                 | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| cid            | int(20) unsigned     | NO   | PRI | 0       |                |
| id             | int(20) unsigned     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| container      | int(20) unsigned     | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
```

```
mysql> explain 1_topics;
+-----------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type                 | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| cid             | int(10) unsigned     | NO   | PRI | 0       |                |
| id              | int(10) unsigned     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| container       | int(20)              | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
```

Table posts has many millions of entries, topics about a 500k.

cid and id, on both tables are primary combo keys.  cid means Community ID. These tables host many different forums.

Thank you for any help you could give with speeding this stuff up.

Comment: Are you sure the explain plan is from that query? I don't see why it would have `Using temporary; Using filesort`.

Comment: *At first sight*, it is most unexpected the query took so long. Even if there is a 500k entries in the table post, according to the query execution plan, by using your indexes, MySQL has only to examine a few hundred rows. Are you alone on a "test" DB -- or are you running that query on a live system with concurrent access to your tables?

Comment: @SylvainLeroux the reason could be overall server load, but it might also be the case that `t.cid = 1010699` is an edge case that has a lot more rows than the average (which explain shows).

Comment: EDITED: THE EXPLAIN WAS WRONG.  ADDED THE CORRECT EXPLAIN OUTPUT.

Comment: According to the query plan, you have (about) 216 rows such as `t.cid = 1010699`. To match with 49 rows of the subquery. That would lead MySQL to examine at worst something like 11000 combinations. I don't think this is such a huge number than the query took "so long".

Comment: Server is NOT LOADED.  It's my dev computer running Linux with 0 load.

Comment: That's why I don't understand why the query takes so long.  Maybe the combo indexes are the issue?

Answer (score 1):

When JOIN-ing on multiple fields (with AND) it helps to have a composite index on those fields.

In your case you can change your `cid` index in posts to `(cid, container)`, that way mysql will be able to lookup the rows directly (you can still use it for queries with only `cid` conditions).

Also you should probably make it an INNER JOIN (as @AndrewK noted), for better readability.

Comment: THIS !  This solved the issue and the query is as it should be, now.  Blazing fast!

Comment: Good catch Vatev. @Segolene Great you have found an answer (I shouldn't probably, but I'm surprised it done so much difference!) Just by curiosity, could you run `EXPLAIN SELECT` now, and report the number of rows examined, to compare "before" and "after".

Comment: Thank you so much everyone for helping me out with that.    Sylvain: here's the EXPLAIN output, now (sorry for bad formatting.  Can't use <pre> nor newline in reply, apparently).
`|  1 | SIMPLE      | t     | ref  | PRIMARY,cid                 | cid   | 4       | const               |  216 | Using where; Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | p     | ref  | PRIMARY,cid,container,cid_2 | cid_2 | 8       | const,ak_slave.t.id |   12 |     `                     |

Comment: The query is now pretty much immediate (0.00 seconds), btw.

Answer (score 0):

Just by looking at your query you can simplify it.

Since you are reducing the set to where t.cid = 1010699 you are stating that it cannot bet null. So you can use an inner join.

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE p.id 
FROM 1_posts p 
JOIN 1_topics t ON p.container = t.id 
WHERE t.cid = 1010699 AND p.cid = t.cid;
```

EDIT:

As Vatev pointed out removing p.cid = t.cid does change the results of the query. I added it back in the WHERE clause for readability

Comment: You are right about the JOIN being INNER, but that has no impact on performance (mysql will make it an INNER JOIN anyway). Removing `p.cid = t.cid` can make the results different.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, AndrewK.  Unfortunately, your query doesn't return the same results as the initial one.  Besides, it had no impact on performance.

Comment: Andrew, the performance is exactly the same as with the initial query.

Comment: Understood. Do you have an index on the p.container column?

Comment: Absolutely.  It is a regular INDEX().